# C Help interpreting calloc segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, calloc

I have the following lines in my code :

```
DocumentNode *docNode = NULL;
initDocNode(docNode, docID, wordFreq);
```

Here's the initDocNode function

```
void initDocNode(DocumentNode *docNode, int docID, int wordFreq) {
    docNode = calloc(1, sizeof(DocumentNode));
    if (!docNode)
        fprintf(stderr, ....);
    docNode->docID = docID;
    docNode->wordFrequency = wordFreq;
}
```

I have a while loop that creates the docNodes, but at a point I get a segfault with the following backtrace. It looks like it's something happening within calloc. Any help understanding this would be much appreciated.

```
_int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x396fbb8760 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=16)
at malloc.c:3718
3718          set_head(remainder, remainder_size | PREV_INUSE);
(gdb) backtrace

_int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x396fbb8760 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=16)
at malloc.c:3718
0x000000396f88098a in __libc_calloc (n=<optimized out>, elem_size=<optimized out>)
at malloc.c:3187
0x0000000000402270 in initDocNode (docnode=0x0, docID=680, wordFreq=1)
at ../util/indexerUtils.c:59
0x000000000040147b in ReconstructIndex (hashtable=0x7fffc8c561f8,
wordToAdd=0x1c3eab0 "mode", docID=680, wordFreq=1) at src/query_engine.c:337
0x0000000000401209 in ReadFile (file=0x7fffc8c5932a "cs_lvl3.dat")
at src/query_engine.c:267
0x0000000000400eff in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffc8c58998) at src/query_engine.c:147
```

I have a set of words and for each word, I create docNodes for documents that contain the word. I get this seg fault only when i'm processing a word with a long list of matching documents. Is there a limit to how much I can calloc?

Here's the function that reads a file containing words and their matching documents  and creates a hashtable for the data. The contents of the file are in the form:
word number_of_matching_docs doc wordFreq doc wordFreq ...

```
HashTable *ReadFile(char *file){
FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
if (!fp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Couldn't open file %s for reloading.\n", file);
    return NULL;
}

HashTable *hashtable = calloc(1, sizeof(HashTable));
if (!hashtable) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Couldn't allocate memory for hashtable.\n");
    return NULL;
}  
char c;
bool done = false;
while (1){
    int wordLength = 0;
    //keep reading until you find a space
    //this is to determine the length of the word
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != ' '){

        if (c == EOF){
            // but if c is EOF, then we're done reading the file                
            done = true;
            // break out of the loop counting word lenght
            break;
        }

        wordLength++;
    }

    if (done){
        // break out of loop reading file
        break;
    }            
    // now allocate memory for the word and null character
    char *currWord = calloc(wordLength + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (!currWord){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory to store %s\n", currWord);
        continue;
    }
    //now reverse the pointer to the beginning of the word
    fseek(fp, -(wordLength + 1), SEEK_CUR);

    int numFiles;
     // now read the word. If it's unsuccessful, then there's no more lines. exit
    fscanf(fp, "%s %d", currWord, &numFiles);
    printf("Processing %s\n", currWord);
    int i = 0;
    while (numFiles--) {
        int docID;
        int wordCount;
        if (!fscanf(fp, " %d %d", &docID, &wordCount)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Couldn't process document for word, %s.\n", currWord);
            free(currWord);
            continue;
        }
        if (!ReconstructIndex(&hashtable, currWord, docID, wordCount)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Couldn't reconstruct index for word, %s\n", currWord);
            free(currWord);
            continue;
        }
        printf("%s: just processed %d document\n", currWord, i);
        i++;

    }

}
fclose(fp);
return hashtable;
```

}

Here's ReconstructIndex()

```
int ReconstructIndex(HashTable **hashtable, char* wordToAdd, int docID, int wordFreq) {
//get the hash index
int hashIndex = JenkinsHash(wordToAdd, MAX_HASH_SLOT);
// if hash index is not taken
if ((*hashtable)->table[hashIndex] == NULL) {
    // make document node
    DocumentNode *newDocNode = NULL;
    // newDocNode = initDocNode(newDocNode, docID, wordFreq);
    initDocNode(&newDocNode, docID, wordFreq);
    if (!newDocNode) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to make DocumentNode for %s.\n", wordToAdd);
        return 0;
    }
    // make word node with this document node
    WordNode *newWordNode = NULL;
    newWordNode = initWordNode(newWordNode, wordToAdd, newDocNode);
    if (!newWordNode) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to make WordNode for %s.\n", wordToAdd);
        free(newDocNode);
        return 0;
    }
    // make hash table node with this word node
    HashTableNode *newHTNode = NULL;
    newHTNode = initHashTNode(newHTNode, (void*)newWordNode, NULL);
    if (!newHTNode) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to make HashTableNode for %s.\n", wordToAdd);
        free(newDocNode);
        free(newWordNode->word);
        free(newWordNode);
        return 0;
    }
    // put hashtablenode into table at the hash index
    (*hashtable)->table[hashIndex] = newHTNode;

    return 1;
}
// if hash index is taken
else {
    // find word
    HashTableNode *currHTNode = (*hashtable)->table[hashIndex];
    int inHashTable = 0;
    while (currHTNode) {
        WordNode * currWordNode = (WordNode *)(currHTNode->hashKey);
        if (strcmp(wordToAdd, currWordNode->word) == 0){
            inHashTable = 1;
            break;
        }
        currHTNode = currHTNode->next;
    }
    // if word was found
    if (inHashTable) {
        WordNode *currWordNode = (WordNode *)(currHTNode->hashKey);
        // add document to this word's listing in hash index
        // make new document node
        DocumentNode *newDocNode = NULL;
        // newDocNode = initDocNode(newDocNode, docID, wordFreq);
        initDocNode(&newDocNode, docID, wordFreq);
        if (!newDocNode) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to make DocumentNode for %s.\n", wordToAdd);
            return 0;
        }
        // append this new doc node to back of other document nodes
        DocumentNode *lastDocNode = currWordNode->doc;

        while (lastDocNode->next) {
            lastDocNode = lastDocNode->next;               
        }

        lastDocNode->next = newDocNode;
        // free(wordToAdd);      // causes seg fault
        return 1;
    }
    // if word was not found
    else {
        // add word node to hashtable at this index
        // make new document node
        DocumentNode *newDocNode = NULL;
        // newDocNode = initDocNode(newDocNode, docID, wordFreq);
        initDocNode(&newDocNode, docID, wordFreq);
        if (!newDocNode) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to make DocumentNode for %s.\n", wordToAdd);
            return 0;
        }
        // make word node with this document node
        WordNode *newWordNode = NULL;
        newWordNode = initWordNode(newWordNode, wordToAdd, newDocNode);
        if (!newWordNode) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to make WordNode for %s.\n", wordToAdd);
            free(newDocNode);
            return 0;
        }
        // make hash table node with this word node
        HashTableNode *newHTNode = NULL;
        newHTNode = initHashTNode(newHTNode, (void*)newWordNode, NULL);
        if (!newHTNode) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to make HashTableNode for %s.\n", wordToAdd);
            free(newDocNode);
            free(newWordNode->word);
            free(newWordNode);
            return 0;
        }
        // append this new hashtable node to end of other hashtable nodes at hash index
        HashTableNode *lastHTNode = (*hashtable)->table[hashIndex];
        while (lastHTNode->next) {
            lastHTNode = lastHTNode->next;
        }
        lastHTNode->next = newHTNode;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the code for the while loop. You might be getting in an infinite loop and running out of memory.

Comment: I'll add the while loop in a sec. I don't think I have an infinite loop, though. i added a print statement to see my progress and I noticed I get the segfault after calling initDocNode for the 678th doc of the particular word

Comment: As a side note, your `initDocNode` function will have no effect on the caller. The pointer is passed by value so the `docNode =` assignment only affects the argument - it does not affect the variable in the caller.

Comment: @Andrew: what do you mean by fault message? Is it:                0  _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x396fbb8760 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=16)
    at malloc.c:3718
3718       set_head(remainder, remainder_size | PREV_INUSE);

Comment: Why do you `free(currWord);` before doing `continue` in the `while (numFiles--)` loop? On the next iteration of the inner loop, `fscanf` will try to write to freed memory.

Comment: Never mind about the fault message. I thought gdb had more information, but I was mistaken and it doesn't.

Comment: I tried DocumentNode *docNode = NULL and changed initDocNode so I could call it with initDocNode(&docNode, ...) and I still got the same problem. I'm going to try to free currWord at a different location

Comment: @Stralo, the stack trace clearly shows that problem happens when 'ReadFile()' calls 'ReconstructIndex()'; then 'ReconstructIndex()' calls 'initDocNode()'.  Hence, it is critical that all the code on this codepath be revealed in the question.  Please edit the question and add the content of 'ReconstructIndex()'.

Comment: I just added ReconstructIndex.

Comment: After doing `if (!docNode)        fprintf(stderr, ....);` you should exit the program instead of continuing to dereference `docNode`

Comment: `char c;` should be `int c;` . Using `fseek` as you do can be unreliable, try to redo your logic to avoid the fseek. Try running under `valgrind` to find overflows.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **docNode instead of *docNode in function body because change are not reflected outside the function body. It creates a node locally.
To call the funcion pass argument as &docNode.

Comment: You mean declare the function as `void initDocNode(DocumentNode **docNode, int docID, int wordFreq);` and call it using `initDocNode(&docNode, docID, wordFreq);` right?

Comment: Yes, By doing this changes will also reflected at the calling point.